# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'total_item' cannot be null

Tags: laravel, integration, payment-gateway, access-token, payment

I’m trying to create payment integration snap token request, which is a local payment mostly like PayPal. the problem is I couldn’t get request from datatables transactions, and the error output is  Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'total_item' cannot be null.

controller.php

```
public function index() 
{
    return view('midtrans.index');
}

public function payment(Request $request)
{
    // Set your Merchant Server Key
    \Midtrans\Config::$serverKey = env('MIDTRANS_SERVER_KEY');
    // Set to Development/Sandbox Environment (default). Set to true for Production Environment (accept real transaction).
    \Midtrans\Config::$isProduction = false;
    // Set sanitization on (default)
    \Midtrans\Config::$isSanitized = true;
    // Set 3DS transaction for credit card to true
    \Midtrans\Config::$is3ds = true;

    $penjualan  = Penjualan::find(session('id_penjualan'));
    $detail = PenjualanDetail::where('id_penjualan', $penjualan->id_penjualan)->get();

    $validator = \Validator::make(request()->all(), [
        'id_penjualan' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'id_member' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'total_item' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'total_harga'=> 'required| numeric | min:0.01',
        'ppn' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
        'diskon' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
        'bayar' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
        'diterima' => 'required|int|numeric|min:1',
    ]);

    //   $validated = $request->validated();
    \DB::transaction(function() use($request) {              // use($validated)
        $penjualan = Penjualan::create([
            'id_penjualan' => $request->id_penjualan,   // $validated['id_penjualan']
            'id_member' => $request->id_member,
            'total_item' => $request->total_item,
            'total_harga' => $request->total_harga,
            'ppn' => $request->ppn,
            'diskon' => $request->diskon,
            'bayar' => $request->bayar,
            'diterima' => $request->diterima,
            'id_user'  => auth()->user()->id           // Auth::user()->id,
    ]);  

        $params = array(
            'transaction_details' => array(
                'order_id' => rand(),
                'gross_amount' => $penjualan->bayar,
            ),
            'item_details' => array(
                [
                    'id' => $penjualan->id_penjualan,
                    'price' => $penjualan->harga_jual,
                    'quantity' => $penjualan->jumlah,
                    'name' => $penjualan->nama_produk
                ]
            ),
            'customer_details' => array(
                'first_name' => $request->get('uname'),
                'last_name' => '',
                'email' => $request->get('email'),
                'phone' => $request->get('number')
            ),
        );

        $snapToken = \Midtrans\Snap::getSnapToken($params);
        $penjualan->snap_token = $snapToken;
        $penjualan->save();

        $this->response['snap_token'] = $snapToken;
    });
    return view('midtrans.payment', ['snap_token'=>$snapToken]);
}

public function payment_post(Request $request)
{
    $json = json_decode($request->get('json'));
    $penjualan = Penjualan::findOrFail($request->id_penjualan);
    $penjualan->status = $json->transaction_status;
    $penjualan->uname = $request->get('uname');
    $penjualan->email = $request->get('email');
    $penjualan->number = $request->get('number');
    $penjualan->transaction_id = $json->transaction_id;
    $penjualan->order_id = $json->order_id;
    $penjualan->gross_amount = $json->gross_amount;
    $penjualan->payment_type = $json->payment_type;
    $penjualan->payment_code = isset($json->payment_code) ? $json->payment_code : null;
    $penjualan->pdf_url = isset($json->pdf_url) ? $json->pdf_url : null;
    return $order->save() ? redirect(url('/'))->with('alert-success', 'Order berhasil dibuat') : redirect(url('/'))->with('alert-failed', 'Terjadi kesalahan');
}
```

does anyone can help what I’m missing? thanks

Comment: you can check data or `$fill` in your model

Comment: This error occure when your field is required and it not receiving data. For this you check that data is passing through this column or check Fillable array in model it contain total_item coulmn in array or not.

Comment: please check you Penjualan migration again, does column "total_item" nullable ? don't forget to add "total_item" into model Penjualan $fillable